# Will setstate run after Object map in this scenario?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
export function getMembersInDB(status) {
  if (this.state.data) {
    let membersObject = this.props.members;
    let membersList = [];

    Object.keys(membersObject).map(async (key) => {
      membersObject[key]['uid'] = key;
      membersObject[key]['profilePic'] = require("../../assets/img/empty-avatar.png");

      if (membersObject[key]['mStatus'] == status) {
        membersList.push(membersObject[key]);
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      data: membersList,
      loading: false,
    });
  }
}
```

With the whole async thing, I'm wondering.  Will this.setState wait for Object.keys map to finish executing before it's set or is there a chance this.setState will update before?

Comment: use Promise.all to wrap around the Object.keys, and make `getMembersInDB` into an async function will be able to make the setState to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that technophyle is correct.

They're correct that the `membersList` will be filled before `setState` is called, but if you have asynchronous calls in the map, `membersList` **will not** be filled before `setState` is called!

See the below code at https://repl.it/repls/KindWeeAddin.

In the first case "`membersListWait`" is empty after the `.map` but "`membersList`" is filled after the `.map`.

```
function getMembersInDB() {
  let membersObject = {prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3};
  let membersListWait = [];
  let membersList = [];

  Object.keys(membersObject).map(async (key) => {
      await sleep(1000);
      membersListWait.push(membersObject[key]);
  });

  Object.keys(membersObject).map(async (key) => {
      membersList.push(membersObject[key]);
  });

  console.log(membersListWait) // prints "[]"
  console.log(membersList) // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}   

getMembersInDB()
```

Answer (score 1):

With or without `async`, your code in the `map` block will run for all iterations first, before `setState()` is called.

It's because:

- First of all, `async` is not doing anything in your code right now, since there is no asynchronous operation in it.
- If there's any asynchronous action (like promise), then `setState()` will run before that asynchronous action, since it'll run in the next iteration (with or without `await`).